# Firesharp: An error occured while execute request. Path : 0/ , Method : PUT

Tags: c#, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, fire-sharp

I am exploring Firebase Realtime Database (RTDB) with C#, and am trying out the Firesharp framework on a .NET console app. I have followed most online tutorials on getting started, but was not able to post any data to my RTDB. I am thrown this error at `AddData().Wait()`:

> System.AggregateException has been thrown
>
> "One or more errors occurred. (An error occured while execute request. Path : 0/ , Method : PUT)"

My implementation is like so:

```
class Program
{
    static IFirebaseConfig config = new FirebaseConfig
    {
        AuthSecret="MY_AUTH_SECRET",
        BasePath="https://MY_APP.firebaseio.com/"
    };

    static IFirebaseClient client;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        client = new FireSharp.FirebaseClient(config);

        if (client != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Connection established!");
            AddData().Wait(); //Crashed here with above error
        }
    }

    public static async Task AddData() 
    {
        var data = new Data
        {
            id = "Hello",
            text = "World"
        };

        SetResponse response = await client.SetAsync("0/", data);
        Data result = response.ResultAs<Data>();
    }
}
```

I am fairly new to C#. Where have I gone wrong?

I'm using VS on Mac, and hence not writing a form app to test instead.

### Edit

Full error log:

> System.AggregateException: "One or more errors occurred. (An error
> occured while execute request. Path : 0 , Method : PUT)" --->
> System.Exception {FireSharp.Exceptions.FirebaseException}: "An error
> occured while execute request. Path : 0 , Method : PUT" --->
> System.Exception {System.IO.FileNotFoundException}: "Could not load
> file or assembly 'System.Security.Permissions, Version=0.0.0.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. The system cannot
> find the file specified.\n"
>
> at at
> Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonTypeReflector.get_DynamicCodeGeneration()\n
> at
> Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonTypeReflector.get_ReflectionDelegateFactory()\n
> at
> Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.GetDefaultCreator(Type
> createdType)\n   at
> Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.InitializeContract(JsonContract
> contract)\n   at
> Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.CreateObjectContract(Type
> objectType)\n   at
> Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.CreateContract(Type
> objectType)\n   at
> Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.ResolveContract(Type
> type)\n   at
> Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.Serialize(JsonWriter
> jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)\n   at
> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.SerializeInternal(JsonWriter
> jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)\n   at
> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObjectInternal(Object value, Type
> type, JsonSerializer jsonSerializer)\n   at
> FireSharp.RequestManager.PrepareRequest(HttpMethod method, Uri uri,
> Object payload)\n   at
> FireSharp.RequestManager.RequestAsync(HttpMethod method, String path,
> QueryBuilder queryBuilder, Object payload)
>
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---   at
> FireSharp.RequestManager.RequestAsync(HttpMethod method, String path,
> QueryBuilder queryBuilder, Object payload)\n   at
> FireSharp.FirebaseClient.SetAsync[T](String path, T data)\n   at
> FiresharpTest.Program.AddData() in
> /Users/MYNAME/Desktop/C#Projects/FiresharpTest/FiresharpTest/Program.cs:40
>
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---   at
> System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout,
> CancellationToken cancellationToken)\n   at
> System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait()\n   at
> FiresharpTest.Program.Main(String[] args) in
> /Users/MYNAME/Desktop/C#Projects/FiresharpTest/FiresharpTest/Program.cs:28

Comment: Try `await client.SetAsync("0", data);` instead

Comment: Are you sure the client has permission to write to the database? By default nowadays no such permission is granted.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen How do i check on this? This line `Console.WriteLine("Connection established!");` prints successfully, so I presume its connected. I have also checked the security rules on firebase console, and are set to public.

Comment: @samthecodingman have tried that as well, but still throws the same error.

Comment: Hmm...public read/write should be good enough. I'm not sure what's going wrong in that case, since the error message is rather vague. Is there any way you can see if there's a nested exception?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I have added the full log inside my question. See edit

Comment: There seem to be lots of other error messages in there, about an assembly not loading, and an issue with parsing JSON. Did you search for those yet?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I do not quite understand where does all these json serialization errors originate from, i am barely getting started. About the assembly loading, what file are we talking about?

Comment: this is the tutorial that i follow: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jZMwwZHJXJc&list=PLuv4McUMmyAbsNdfZ4rH_OyEM3P2MJS-F

Comment: did you solve the problem ?

Comment: @DarioN1 yes I did, pls see answer below.

Comment: my problem was related to different version of newtonsoft dll...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so the problem to this issue was that I had two Nuget packages installed, `Firesharp` and `Firesharp.Serialization.JsonNet`.

I removed `Firesharp` and then made amendments to my `AddData()` function, and it all worked.

```
public static async Task AddData() 
{
    var data = new Data
    {
        id = "Hello",
        text = "World"
    };

    SetResponse response = await client.SetTaskAsync("0", data); //Change to SetTaskAsync here
    Data result = response.ResultAs<Data>();
}
```